# Output Streaming multiple files into a zip file

Tags: java, angularjs

Hie ,  I m generating report in csv format using solr , angularjs , Jax-rs and java. The input stream contain a csv response already because we have specified wt=csv while querying solr. Size of csv created from every input Stream might be 300mb .At java layer code is some thing like :

```
enter code here
     InputStream is1;  
     InputStream is2;
     // for is1 let  file  is csv1
     // for is2  let file is  csv2
     // csvzip is the csv created form both two files 
     // now csvzip need to be downloaded through a popup
```

Creating big size file and zipfile in memory will not be a good approach surely.
Is there is any way to handle this?

Comment: How would you create a zip? Using a ZipOutputStream, right? A ZipOutputStream wraps an OutputStream. What you write to an OutputStream usually doesn't stay in memory. For example, if you write to the HTTP response output stream, it goes to the browser, over the network, which is precisely what you want.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah thanks. But when we are creating csv from input stream Can we make folder on server and create multiple csv there and than we can access all csv and zip and stream that. Or u can suggest other approach

Comment: Why would you do that? Just read bytes from the CSV input stream, and write them to the zip output stream. What would you gain from reading from the CSV input stream, writing to a file, opening the file, reading from the file input stream and writing to the zip output stream? You would just make things more complex, and slower.

Comment: @JBNizet No things is that there is a while loop which will create multiple input stream. And my zip file should contain a individual csv file belongings to each input stream

Comment: @JBNizet thanks got your point

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You would like your zip file to contain a single entry, which would be the concatenation of your two ZipInputStream, is that right? If so, that doesn't change much. You would still create a ZipOutputStream, create a single entry, copy all the bytes from the first csv input stream to the zip output stream, then copy all the bytes from the second csv input stream to the zip output stream, then close the entry and the zip stream.